# Making radio button label centred vertically in form-check div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to center radio button text vertically.

problem is, sometimes the text occupy two lines and sometimes one line only.

I can't find a css solution to centre text vertically for both one line and two lines.

I am using bootstrap, my html code is

```css
.form-check {
  top: 13.33333px;
  min-height: 85px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  padding: 10px 45px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.form-check .form-check-input {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row spacerow mt-3">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 mt-2">
      <div>Questions
      </div>


      <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 mt-2">
          <div class="form-check">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="one" name="One" value="1" checked>One line sentence
            <label class="form-check-label" for="One"></label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 mt-2">
          <div class="form-check">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="One" name="One" value="1" checked>Two lines radio buttons text which is centered inside form-check div

            <label class="form-check-label" for="One"></label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot of layout

[image]

Please help me to center the text in one line vertically.

thanks

Comment: use flex on the form-check with align-items center

Comment: I've converted your posted code into a live demo, so the results can be seen; could you please add a link to the relevant version of Bootstrap?